# Error in opening stream from localhost in wampserver

Tags: php, mysql, wampserver

I am using wampserver. i already got connection successful in database.However, i cannot insert data in database. I have my folder named uomwebapplication in which there are 2 php files named :init and register.
My init.php file is working well but not my register.php file.Help me!!!!!!!!
Here are my codes:

init.php

```
<?php
$db_name="uomwebappdb";
$mysql_user="root";
$mysql_pass="";
$server_name="localhost";

$con=mysqli_connect($server_name,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$db_name);
if(!$con)
{
  echo"Connection Error...".mysqli_connect_error();
} else {
  echo"<h3>Database connection Success...</h3>";
}
?>
```

register.php

```
<?php

require"init"; 
$name="ak";
$surname="shay";
$password="shayak";

$sql_query="insert into user_information 
               values('$name','$surname','$password');";

if(mysqli_query($con,$sql_query))
{
    echo"<h3> Data Insertion Success...</h3>";
} else {
    echo"Data Insertion Error...".mysqli_error($con);
}
?>
```

ERROR

1)    Warning: require(init): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\uomwebapplication\register.php on line 7

2)     Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'init' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\uomwebapplication\register.php on line 7

Answer (score 0):

In `register.php`, you have the following line:

```
require"init"
```

Shouldn't that be

```
require 'init.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no file called **init** in the same folder where register.php is placed. Maybe you forgot to add .php?
2. This is error messsage of fallback. It couldnt find the file near register.php then php engine tried to look file **init** in the all pathes specified in include_path variable of php config but failed to locate.

Answer (score 0):

hi you have some one errors
first your conection maybe you can make from other form or method 
more easy example
init.php

```
<?php
function Conect()
{
    if (!($link=mysql_connect("localhost","username","password")))
    {
        echo "Error to connect to database.";
        exit();
    }
    if (!mysql_select_db("database_name",$link))
    {
        echo "Error on select to  database.";
        exit();
    }
    return $link;
}
```

for make a insert 
register.php

```
<?php
include('init.php');
$link=Conect(); 
$value1=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['value1']);
$value2=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['value2']);
$value3=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['value3']);

$query="insert into table_name(column1, column2, column3)".
       "values('$value1','$value2','$value3')";
$action =mysql_query($query,$link);

     if (!$action) {
       die('don't insert register: ' . mysql_error());
     ?> <font color="blue" face="arial" size="4">can't insert register</font> <?php

     }


     ?> <font color="blue" face="arial" size="4">register insert</font> <?php

     mysql_close($link);
```

and for sql injection you can use the session or login validate

only if a user is login can insert.
good luck,,,

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to do a proper check that the connection was made, and not output a message if the connection was correctly made, as this may effect other things like `header('Location: .....')` command you may get to later.

init.php

```
<?php
$db_name="uomwebappdb";
$mysql_user="root";
$mysql_pass="";
$server_name="localhost";

$con=mysqli_connect($server_name,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$db_name);
if (!$con) {
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
        . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```

Now in `registrer.php` the file you are including is `init.php` so you need the extension as well as the filename

```
<?php

require "init.php"; 

$name="ak";
$surname="shay";
$password="shayak";

$sql_query="insert into user_information 
               values('$name','$surname','$password');";

if(mysqli_query($con,$sql_query))
{
    echo"<h3> Data Insertion Success...</h3>";
} else {
    echo"Data Insertion Error...".mysqli_error($con);
}
?>
```

You should make [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) your friend